# insertar valores de usuario y haga operacion

Tags: java, text

hola amigos de SO estoy haciendo un programa sencillo en java con applets como practica pero no se como hacer que el textfield obtenga valores solo enteros del usuario y realice una operacion sencilla como una suma y aparezca como ejemplo un valor numérico entero con 2 botones que convierta en kelvin y centigrados

y aun no logro hacerlo me podrían ayudar, se los agradezco

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class IApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener{
  Button b,c;
  TextField t;
  Label i;
  public void init(){
    b=new Button("Kelvin");
    c=new Button("Centigrados");
    t=new TextField(30);
    i=new Label("*******");
    add(b);add(c);add(t);add(i);
    b.addActionListener(this);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     i.setText(t.getText());
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es tu error en si? Se mas especifico.

Comment: no es un error como tal sino mas bien no se como obtener un valor de tipo entero del textfield para realizar la operación por ejemplo para que kelvin sea  i=i+270;